# How do I get a status to only update when necessary in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a 5th Edition D&D Character Generator App (I know, super nerdy). I'm trying to have certain questions asked based on what level the character is at. Now what I want it to do is to only update information instead of reasking for all of the same information. For example, if a character is a Ranger at level 1, it will ask what favored terrain and favored enemies. If I have the character go up to level 2, it will reask those questions AND ask the next question related to level 2. How do I have it just update with the information gathered by level 2 and so on?

I believe this question will also answer how do I update experience points and not have to ask the same questions over and over again. If not, that is my next question.

Thanks.

Here is the sample of the code in question:

```
if (level >= 1){
            var favTerrain1 = prompt("Name your favorite terrain.");
            var favEnemy1 = prompt("Name your favorite enemy type or 2 humanoid races. (If you select the latter, please separate with a comma.)");
            document.getElementById("level1").innerHTML = "<h4><b> Favored Terrain: </b>" + favTerrain1 + "<br><b>Favored Enemy(Enemies): </b>" + favEnemy1 + "</h4>";
        }
        if (level >= 2) {
            var lv2 = +prompt("Choose fighting style: 1. Archery 2. Defense 3. Dueling 4. Two-Weapon Fighting");
            var level2;
            switch(lv2){
                case 1:
                    level2 = "<b>Archery</b> You gain +2 bonus attack rolls you make with ranged weapons.";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    level2 = "<b>Defense</b> While you are wearing armor, you gain a +1 to armor class.";
                    armorClass = armorClass + 1;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    level2 = "</b>Dueling</b> When you are wielding a melee weapon and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    level2 = "<b>Two-Weapon Fighting</b> When you engage in two-weapon fighting, you can add your ability modifier to the damage of the second attack.";
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                level2= " ";
            }
```

It will ask both level1 and level2 sets of questions if I upgrade the level from 1 to 2.

Comment: A link to some of the code you're currently using would be helpful, as I'm not 100% clear if you're already stuck with this problem or just in the planning stages.

Comment: Updated question with sample code.

Comment: hah, was writing out my answer while you were adding this code. Thank you! I think my answer still suffices. I'm not actually certain how you're building up your character info object in your code snippet, but let me know if my answer needs more detail to fit with your code.

Answer (score 0):

By building your character you're creating an Object in the most classic way: the character has a number of attributes that build as they level up.

To prompt the user for only the questions necessary, you can check to see if the `player` object already has the properties you would gain at that level with the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) function.

So you could use something like

```
var player = new Object();
player.favoredTerrain = "jungle";

if (!player.hasOwnProperty('favoredMount')){
    //whatever your code is to ask for the favored mount
};

if (!player.hasOwnProperty('favoredTerrain')){
    //whatever code in here won't run because he has a favored Terrain already!
};
```

Note that a number of frameworks will make stuff like this *much* easier to do over a large list of values e.g. Angular's test to see if X value is populated and then hide/unhide questions. Alternatively, JQuery will make it easy to select and hide blocks of questions that you already have answered. Since your question was 'how do I do this with Javascript' I tried to give the 'pure' version

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It keeps doing the same questions over again. Maybe if I try one of the frameworks, it might help, but I don't know much about them. Any help in this department?